# PHP will not pass variable to included file

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

So on my first page I have:

```
$templateCSS = 'direct_grid_V2';
$this->load->view('direct_header_v2');
//..and so on
```

In the included file (direct_header_v2.php) I have

```
echo $templateCSS;
```

but it will not display. What could I be doing wrong? Will it not pass to an included file?

Comment: That's not an included file... that's a file loaded by your controller system. Totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the date to view during load. Example:

```
$data['templateCSS'] = 'direct_grid_V2';
$this->load->view('direct_header_v2', $data);
```

Then you can echo in view page

```
echo $templateCSS;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing any array or data to the view ?!
in case you are loading multiple view you need to pass the array to the first one so that other views can see it.